# Google sign in extended token

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth

**My question:**

How can I receive an extended token so the user won't be logged out after an hour or so? I intentionally requested an offline access because I read that I have to in order to receive a refresh token. But I'm not receiving it in the `authResult` java-script variable.

---

**My code:**

This is how my users sign in to my site with their Google account:

1 - A sign in button is presented.

```
<span id="signinButton">
    <span class="g-signin" data-callback="signinCallback" data-clientid="********.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-access_type="offline" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction" data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/offline"></span>
</span>
```

2 - After the user click on the button, an ajax call is being made and the access token is passed on to the server.

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {

  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    //Shoot the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //...Send the access token to the server
    })
        .done(function(msg) {

            //...Do somthing after a sucessfull login

        });

  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

3 - A PHP function receives the token and saves it in the `$_SESSION` variable for later use.

```
public function GoogleAuth($token) {

    $_SESSION['google_token'] = $token;

    #See that the token is valid
    $session_status = $this->GetSessionStatus($token, 'all');
    if ($session_status == false) {
        return $session_status;
    }

    #If token is valid, manage the registration/login process
    //...

}
```

4 - Here is the function that check if the token is valid:

```
public function GetSessionStatus($token) {

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';
    $params = 'access_token='.$token;

    $ch = curl_init($url . '?' . $params);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    if (!empty($headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $user = curl_exec($ch); 
    $user = json_decode($user);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (isset($user->id)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

**Again with my question in case you forgot :)**

So this is how I handle the sign in. I'm not sure that I'm doing it properly, but it works.
My question is how can I receive an extended token so the user won't be logged out after an hour or so. I intentionally requested an offline access because I read that I have to in order to receive a refresh token. But I'm not receiving it in the `authResult` java-script variable.

**Edit: At end (how it was solved):**

First, instead of using the `$_SESSION`, I used `$_COOKIE`. It's more permanent.

Second, I switch to all PHP sdk in order to receive the refresh token.

Comment: I am not sure why you dont use Googles client lib https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.   But you should be getting a refresh token back you use that to get a new access token when it expires.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will use the SDK, it's probably better than what I have right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript means you're using the so-called OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant and that grant type cannot return refresh tokens due to security constraints. The spec says in section https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2:

> The authorization server MUST NOT issue a refresh token.

This is because a Javascript client cannot securely store long lived tokens. It would be better for you to use a server side flow e.g. using the `google-api-php-client` so you can also store and reuse the refresh token in a secure way.